# setParams can not be called by root navigator

Tags: react-native, react-router

I am working on a react native application on ios. I want to do some custom logic on navigation header back button click. My code of router.js is:

```
export const ProjectStack = createStackNavigator({

Question:{
screen: Question,

     navigationOptions: {
  title: 'Frage',
  headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton  onPress={() => navigationOptions.state.handleSave()} />

},
  },
});
```

And in the component i am doing this:

```
componentDidMount(){

  this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleSave: this._saveDetails });
}

_saveDetails() {
  console.log("Back Button Clicked");
  }
```

When the component loads i get the exception :

```
Invariant violation: setParams can not be called by root navigator
```

Whats the issue, i am unable to find the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only modify navigation options for a navigator from one of its screen components. This applies equally to navigators that are nested as screens. ([Documentation link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#docsNav))

The correct way of doing this will be

**Set Navigation options in component**

```
class Filters extends React.Component {

 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const handleSave = navigation.getParam("handleSave", () => {});
    return {
      title: 'Frage',
      headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton onPress={handleSave} />
    };
  };
```

**and set in componentDidMount of component**

```
componentDidMount(){

  this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleSave: this._saveDetails });
}

_saveDetails = () => {
  console.log("Back Button Clicked");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Mehran Khan

Comment: What do you mean by. “one of its screen components”?

Answer (score 0):

For me, what seemed to be the problem is that navigation was done using [navigation ref](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop), with key set to random number, converting it to string seemed to solve it

```
const navigate = (routeName, params) => {
  navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
      key: String(Math.random() * 10000),
      // key: Math.random() * 10000, // -> this was the problem
    })
  );
};
```

I searched in node_modules for the error and got this,

```
 setParams: params => {
      invariant(
        route.key && typeof route.key === 'string',
        'setParams cannot be called by root navigator'
      );
      return NavigationActions.setParams({ params, key: route.key });
    },
```

in this file

```
node_modules/react-navigation/src/routers/getNavigationActionCreators.js
```

which helped me figure it out.
hope this helps somebody